# How I am able to use To_date function in oracle with date format?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have column exp_date as date format with NLS value as `DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` in SQL developer,
I am using select `to_date(exp_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from demo;`

Why I am not facing any error if to_date function only accepts string as paramater.

Comment: I have no idea what Oracle does when the first argument is a date:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=97f4a8ebed3ecb7fd7695a8170ab85aa.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That is explained by the [String-To-Date conversion rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5). `MM` also matches `MON` and `RR` also matches `RRRR`.

Comment: I hope you do this only as a test. Running `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE` is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle tries to be helpful and implicitly converts `exp_date` to a string to match the expected first argument of `TO_DATE`. So, your query:

```sql
select to_date(exp_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from demo;
```

Is an equivalent of the more explicit date-to-string conversion in this query:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(
           exp_date,
           ( SELECT value
             FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
             WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
           )
         ),
         'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       )
FROM   demo;
```

Where the `exp_date` value has been cast to a string. It works because it just so happens that the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and your format model for `TO_DATE` are the same.

Comment: . . Look at the db<>fiddle I reference above.  Oracle is doing something strange.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nothing strange there as the [String-to-date conversion rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-5B755E80-3CB2-4901-BBCF-F0FC764E0BB5) are working as expected, [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ac83c101d8ea5db96b5e42130a1a9204) Apart from the middle query, you are matching the different format models and it is no surprise that you are getting day-month-year (or even century) values come through incorrectly.