# In Oracle 10g how can i store this format 1/4/2022 12:00:00 AM in Column of type Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to store this **1/4/2022 12:00:00 AM** in column of type Date but i get this error **ORA-01843: not a valid month**  can i get any help if it is possible to do this in oracle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I am able to use To\_date function in oracle with date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64224093/how-i-am-able-to-use-to-date-function-in-oracle-with-date-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_date` function with appropriate format model.

In your example, it is unclear what `1/4/2022` represents (is it 1st of April or 4th of January) so I tried to guess it.

```
SQL> create table test (col date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (col) values (to_date('1/4/2022 12:00:00 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am'));

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

How to fetch that value?

One option is to do similarly as while inserting data, but this time with the `to_char` function:

```
SQL> select to_char(col, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') result from test;

RESULT
----------------------
01/04/2022 12:00:00 AM
```

Another option is to alter session; then `select * from test` returns desired result:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

COL
----------------------
01/04/2022 12:00:00 AM

SQL>
```

---

AM/PM differentiation: Oracle *knows* what you entered:

```
SQL> insert into test (col) values (to_date('1/4/2022 2:30:00 PM', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am'));

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

COL
----------------------
01/04/2022 12:00:00 AM
01/04/2022 02:30:00 PM

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you a lot Littlefoot it insert it was 1st of Apri. but in database i get this format 01-APR-22 can't i get this '1/4/2022 12:00:00 AM'

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: ook thank you, other question is no way to detect if it is am or pm when you fetch

Comment: Oracle detects it itself; it depends on what you inserted. Have a look at another example I posted.

Comment: very nice explanation, thank you